# Run firebase function on deployment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to trigger a firebase function to run on deployment, and only once?

Currently if I want to perform a bulk insert for my firestore database, I expose a HTTP function, and only allow it to be triggered if the request contains a secret key stored in config.

Comment: There is no "on deploy trigger" that can detect if there was a new deployment.

Instead I think that you're already onto a solution with the API endpoint that triggers a job. What you might want to look into is to create a CI/CD setup and using curl to call that https function after you have successfully deployed a new version.